# de.hybris.platform.jalo.Jalo SystemException: no attribute ImpEx Import CronTab.sendEmail OnFailure found[HY--1]

Tags: insert-update, sap-commerce-cloud, impex

Hybris[Impex script import] : 
Getting below exception while importing the impex script.

de.hybris.platform.jalo.Jalo SystemException: no attribute ImpEx Import CronTab.sendEmail OnFailure found[HY--1]

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when we are using the db dump for the first time.

I have resolved this. Need to do system update by selecting the all extensions in Hac.

It worked.

Comment: hybris needs to have an up to date representation of the type system in the database. Meaning that every itemtype, every attribute must have its representation in the database. When you add a new type, attribute or relation, you need to update the type system in the database. You do that with "Update running system". So when you did system update, the new attribute CronTab.sendEmailOnFailure was added to the database and now you can use it in your impex statement.

Comment: > This issue occurs when we are using the db dump for the first time.\

Then your DB Dump is not complete, as it should contain all metadata tables, assuming the `cronjob` table in your dump already contains the attribute `CronTab.sendEmail OnFailure`